# UI Plugin is not loaded on project pages

Tags: user-interface, plugins, rundeck

I have written a simple Rundeck UI plugin. The purpose of the plugin is to inject content into a project dashboard.

By inspecting the page, I see that the plugin is loaded (and the JS runs) on all pages except the project pages. There is nothing I can do to make the plugin available to project pages. Are UI plugins disabled on project pages?

plugin.yaml

```
ui:
    - pages: '*'
      scripts:
        - js/main.js
```

Comment: Which Rundeck version are you using? On the new Rundeck 3.4 branch some 3.3.X UI elements are broken, actually, this [example](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/ui-plugin-examples) doesn't work on rundeck 3.4.6. But if you add that plugin on rundeck 3.3.X you can see it on the Dashboard page.

Comment: We are using rundeck 3.4.6. Thats a shame. We wanted to customise a project DashBoard.

Answer (score 0):

On the new Rundeck 3.4 branch some 3.3.X UI elements are broken (for example, from some UI plugins), actually, [this](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/ui-plugin-examples) example doesn't work on rundeck 3.4.6. But if you add that plugin on rundeck 3.3.X you can see it on the Dashboard page.